# How to sort a MS-Excel Table column after a user entry using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add the automatic sorting capability to an Excel Table column after entering an item in that column range. The following script is already inserted in the desired Worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub WorksheetActivate()
    ' Sorts table automatically after each entry

    Dim WKSeriesList    As Sort
    
    Set WKSeriesList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").Sort

    WKSeriesList.SortFields.Clear
    'Clear previous sorting method

    With WKSeriesList
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("KitchenLinesTable[[#All],[Kitchen Series]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a Worksheet_change event

Comment: @Scott Craner, please can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1):

The Worksheet_Change event detects any change in column 'Kitchen Series' and calls the **sortTable**  procedure that as some arguments: Table name, Column name, Type of sorting.

Put this code in your **sheet module**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("KitchenLinesTable[[#All],[Kitchen Series]]")) Is Nothing Then
        Call sortTable("KitchenLinesTable", "Kitchen Series", xlAscending)
    End If
End Sub
```

Put this code on a **standard module**

```
Sub sortTable(tblName As String, colName As String, sOrder As XlSortOrder)
    Dim ol As ListObject: Set ol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName)
    Dim olColRng As Range: Set olColRng = ol.ListColumns(colName).DataBodyRange
    
    ol.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    ol.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=olColRng, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=sOrder, _
        DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    
    With ol.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```